# Is it possible to tail-recursively traverse directory in Scala?

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion

I'm attempting to write a Scala function to list all files/subdirectories under a given directory, but I'd like to make it tail recursive.  Before I spend any more time on this is it even an attainable goal, or should I stick to regular recursion?  I just want to know that it is possible, as I'd like to figure it out for myself.  Good learning experience and all that.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to have a support for symlinks?

Comment: Hmm, don't think so.

Comment: Then your task boils down to ordinary tree traversal which is known to be implementable in tail-recursive way.

Comment: I think you'll end up with something like `def walkTree(pathToRead: Path, remainingPaths: List[Path])` where Path is something like File or maybe a String pathname, whatever works out best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems you need some type of stack for tree traversal, so if you avoid the system stack you have to implement your own (see http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/7984)

Comment: Not sure why this got a down vote since it's pretty much correct. You need somehow to maintain your position in the tree. This can be implicitly in the call stack (and your function will not be tail recursive) or explicitly in some other datastructure passed from call to call.